# Sessions are going crazy. Only Mozilla is able to process

Tags: php, session, browser

**PROBLEM**

---

I've got an admin panel. Currently only Mozilla is able to process log ins. Browsers like Chrome, IE, Opera won't even show any message carried through sessions thus no one is able to log in any browser but Mozilla.

**SOME INFORMATION**

---

- I'm using **PHP 5.3.6** on my server, **PHP 5.3.5** on my local
  computer.
- My code is Object Oriented.
- `ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1);` and
  `ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);` are used in construction method
  of my session class.
- This website on SLL

**Login process:** First I gather all information from form, validate and gather data. After validation if everything is right, I send this data to **login** method in my **session class**.

```
public function login ($user) {
        global $siteSettings;
        if ($user) {            
            $this->id          = $_SESSION['id']          = $user->id;
            $this->username    = $_SESSION['username']    = $user->username;
            $this->fullName   = $_SESSION['fullName']   = $user->fullName;
            $this->group_id    = $_SESSION['group_id']    = $user->group_id;
            $this->groupName    = $_SESSION['groupName']      = $user->groupName;
            $this->lastLogin   = $_SESSION['lastLogin']   = $user->lastLogin;
            $this->isAdmin   = $_SESSION['isAdmin']   = ($user->admin == 1) ? true : false;
            $this->isAgent   = $_SESSION['isAgent']   = ($user->agent == 1) ? true : false;
            self::$language   = $_SESSION['language'] = ($user->language != "" || $user->language != NULL) ? $user->language : self::$language;
            if ($user->language != "" || $user->language != NULL) {
                $_SESSION['language'] = $user->language;
            }else {
                if (!defined(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE)) {
                    $browserLang = "|".$_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"];
                    $browserLang = getStringBetween($browserLang, "|","-", FALSE);
                    if (!file_exists(LANGUAGES.$browserLang.".php")) $browserLang = FALSE;
                }
                $_SESSION['language'] = ($browserLang) ? $browserLang : DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
            }


            # When 2 Update session_id
            $date = new DateTime("now");
            $UpdateTime = $siteSettings->session->timeOut * 60;
            $date->add(new DateInterval("PT".$UpdateTime."S"));

            $_SESSION['SIDUpdateTime'] = $date->format("Y-m-d G:i:s");

            # UPDATE LAST LOGIN & ADD SESSION ID
            # Clear Fields
            members::clearFields();
            members::$fields['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
            members::$fields['lastLogin'] = date("Y.m.d G:i:s");
            members::$fields['lastLoginIP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            # GET THE SALT
            $saltInfo = members::getData("id", "salt", members::$fields['id']);

            # SETTING SESSION ID ENCRYPTION
            crypt::setKey($saltInfo->salt);
            members::$fields['sessionID'] = crypt::encode(session_id());
            members::$fields['sessionIP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            members::$fields['sessionAgent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            members::save();

            $this->loggedIn = true;
            var_dump($_SESSION);
        }
    }
```

When I dumb the data I can see $_SESSION got some values.

Just to test it, I stopped the script where after `var_dump($_SESSION);` (added `die();`) I created test.php file and tried this;

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo '<pre>';

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Output is `array(0) {}`

But when I try exactly the same thing with Mozilla, output of test.php is the way it should be (matching with login method's result in my session class).

- I have tried from my local computer and I don't experience the same
  problem.
- I disabled all java script and jquery codes from the page just to
  have no 'maybe' in my mind.
- After dumping the data, script is stopped. That's why `$_SESSION` variable shouldn't change. For some reason when it is on the server only **Mozilla** is able to show expected result while other browsers shows `NULL`.

---

At this point I really don't know what to think of about this problem to try to solve it. All I can think of is, this problem is possibly related to server configuration. But then, PHP is server side programming. PHP shouldn't display different behavior for browsers like Jquery, CSS, HTML...

I'm sorry, I can't provide admin panel link. Considering this is an active admin panel. If necessary I could install it on another domain to let you try but I believe the information I gave above explains everything.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Can I ask what this syntax accomplishes? `$this->id = $_SESSION['id'] = $user->id;`

Comment: It's shorthand for settings multiple variables to the same value (the last one).

Comment: Oh wow - that's very helpful. Thanks! +1 to `Pixeler` and `jprofitt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Mozilla FireFox is able to process some data but other browsers I tried with are not and therefore they reset the whole session with each page load.

I had no problem with my local computer but on the server I had sessions problem. I don't know why `session_set_cookie_params();` and `setcookie();` didn't work on the server so I had to code longer version;

```
private static function sessionLifeTime() {
global $siteSettings;
# HOW LONG WE WANT SESSIONS
$lifeTime = intval($siteSettings->session->timeOut) * 60;

if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && isset($_SESSION['lastActivity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['lastActivity'] > $lifeTime) ) {
// SEND INFORMATION TO USER
self::logout();
}
$_SESSION['lastActivity'] = time();
}
```

Replacing my method with the code above solved the problem.

Thank you all for your time, concern and interest.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem... just enable the cookies.. so that after login the code to set the sessions will be executed and the sessions will be set. may be the sessions r not able to set...

also check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-limiter.php

Comment: I added more information in my question. Thank you for your time Parchee. I am checking `session_cache_limiter` right now. That might be the solution. I will report back. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

If something large doesn't work, trim it down, test & debug, and build up from there.

Does this work? (Run it twice).

```
<?php

session_start();

echo "Session ID: " . session_id() . "<br/>\n";

if (!isset($_SESSION['test']))
{
    $_SESSION['test'] = "foobar";
    echo "Setting session variable: ";
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
}
else
{
    echo "Restoring session variable: ";
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
}
```

If this works in all browsers, it's got something to do with your code. An empty session might have something to do with a cookie that can't be written, for example. Also set error reporting to E_ALL | E_STRICT, so you'll see everything that goes wrong.

Comment: Hello CodeCaster, thank you for your time. As I mentioned in my question, mozilla is working just fine so this is not about my code. PHP won't just unset session depending on which browser you are using (unless programmer wants it and codes for it).

Comment: What does this script display in IE for example? Does the session ID change every request? Your session ID is stored in a cookie. It's almost impossible you found a bug where PHP or Apache refuse to set cookies for other browsers than Firefox. It's more likely there's a client configuration issue (are cookies enabled?) or a programming error on your side.

Comment: As I said, I don't know what to think from this point. It works perfectly in all browsers in my local computer. When I send it to server, it just doesn't work on any other browser than Mozilla. I wrote about my steps. I double checked about sessions. There is nothing wrong with the code I am using or my browsers settings. I might have to add a code or change a setting in php.ini on the server. That's all I can think of.

Comment: If you refuse to answer my questions, I can't help you. It might be that IE sees your online server as "Internet zone" and disables cookies as a policy restriction, for example, while cookies for local addresses ("Intranet zone") are allowed. This way you'll never be able to establish a session outside your network. Furthermore, "It works in one situation so it should always work" is never a good starting point. ;-)

Comment: I'm not refusing CodeCaster, I wrote the output on my question already. Strangely sessions are only working on Mozilla. I added the website to my trusted web sites category in IE still the same.  Considering it is working on my local computer without a problem, I just assumed this has to do with server's php or apache settings. **1.** I will have to double check my `headers` **2.** I might have to test it on another server (it is hard to find good **php 5.3** and above hosting).

Comment: Ok, I'll see when you've found something new. Good luck. :)